# Highlight search result

Tags: c#, javascript

I am going to highlight search result in page better using c# or JavaScript. Problem is that search text and result is in Chinese which have no space between characters. example of this problem is:

```
          var A = abrfct;
          var B= abefhwefoba;
```

so I want to highlight all characters in B which contain any character in A.
in this example : `

I want to highlight: ab, f, b, a in B.

Comment: Is your question "how to highlight letters," or "how to determine what collisions the two strings have"?

Comment: are you going to highlight using some css?

Answer (score 1):

Use [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) library, then you can use things like:

```
var definition = "漢語，又称中文（單指文字）、汉文、华文，其他名稱有唐文、中國語，唐話、中國話等[1]，是属汉藏语系的分析语，具有声调";
var language_but_especially_han = "[汉文]+"
XRegExp.replace(definition, language_but_especially_han, "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>");
```

results in

> 漢語，又称中[文]（單指[文]字）、[汉文]、华[文]，其他名稱有唐[文]、中國語，唐話、中國話等[1]，是属[汉]藏语系的分析语，具有声调

(i.e. 6 matches, of which 4 are 文, one is 汉, and one is 汉文)

Also, posting a real problem instead of a replacement problem will probably get you a better, or faster solution.